# All outcomes for subtraction on each value in list individually

Tags: prolog

As you can see from my predicate iterate, I am repeating `Z is X-3` and `Z is X-2`, the scenarios are different if the value is 0 or greater than 0. thus why the duplicates,

Was wondering if there was a way round this

```
iterate([], []).           %Nothing to change
    iterate([1|T], T).
    iterate([X|T], [Z|T]) :-   % Change only the headT
        (   Z is X - 3
        ;
            Z is X - 2
        ),
        Z>0 .
    iterate([X|T], T) :-   % Change only the head
        (   Z is X - 3
        ;
            Z is X - 2
        ),
        Z is 0 .

    iterate([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-  %Keep the head and change something later
        iterate(Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: Can you change your question title to reflect what your code does

Comment: yeah sorry I'm new here @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo

Comment: It is still extremely unclear to me what this predicate is supposed to do.

Comment: If `~ is X - 3` and `Z is 0`, then the condition can be written simply as `X = 3`. Thus the whole branch can be written as `iterate([X|T], T) :- (X = 3 ; X = 2).`, or perhaps even simpler: `iterate([3|T], T). iterate([2|T], T).` which you seem to be already doing in `iterate([1|T], T).`. But it's really difficult to understand the desired result.